# ionic 4 url segment undefined uncaught in promise

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

When I install the app in real device and open it it does not show any data which comes from backend. when I debug it it shows an error as mention below.  But this is working very well when I run it using ionic cordova run browser.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to this.

reffered url :

[Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'null' in Ionic Angular App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58442320/error-cannot-match-any-routes-url-segment-null-in-ionic-angular-app)

I got the issue because of my sanitizer (iframe)

Answer (score 0):

When your passing data from one component to other via URL , make sure that the data is encoded. In some cases data from backend will be a collection of different symbols such as slashes e.t.c. For Eg: If data comes from backend as in the format of "abc/ss/sd/" and when you pass the data via URL without enocoding,then the portion after the slash will consider as a separate URL. I prefer to use EncodeURI to avoid this so that the data will encode into  a separate format.

Let me put some sample codes

**home.component.ts**

```
 const PassData = {service_name: "Car wash", service_id: 2};
  this.goToPage('/component2/' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(PassData)));
```

**otp.components.ts**

```
 const Data =  decodeURIComponent((this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')));
    this.getData = JSON.parse(Data);
```

**app.route.module.ts** File

```
{
    path: 'otp/:id',
    loadChildren: './otp/otp.module#OtpPageModule'
  }
```